# Formating a Large Text fetched from Database Using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to format a large text from my database into my webpage using PHP.
The text fetched okay from database but the format displayed isn't.
I tried to use the function

> nl2br();  or nl2p();

but I want the first paragraph to appear after the second dot(.) was found(means the first paragraph will be the combination of the first two sentences).

Then from there I could add my image below it , followed by the remaining text strings.

The output should be in this form.

> Hello everyone. This is my first paragraph striped and separated by PHP.
>
> ```
>  (Here comes my image)
> ```
>
> The rest of those remaining text shoul appear here.Below images.

Comment: you can use `span`   tag

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is something you are looking for, but I would use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

If you are sure you have sentences separated by ".", use:

```
$text = explode(".", $article_content);
```

The second line is found on `$text[1]`.
Based on that you could add a break.

This is a pretty weak solution to be honest. Firstly, you cannot be sure they're always separated by a "dot" sign. Secondly, there might be a "dot" in the middle of the sentence, that's not a full stop, for example $3.45. If I were you, I would try to include something you can separate content by, for example `"\r\n"` (new line sign) and then explode by this creating your parts.